# getting HttpSessionEventPublisher Exception at start of application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-security

The application is developed using spring and maven. I am getting following Exception/Error at the start of application.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
```

Comment: Check if your spring-security-core.jar already in your classpath.

Comment: @Hatem It's always a good practice on stackoverflow to let others know if you got solution to your problem or not.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are missing spring security related libraries. Please make sure you have following dependencies mentioned in your pom file.

```
<!-- Spring Security -->
```

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```